# Two ListViews with selected items on the same page

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

Is there a way to have two ListViews on the same form and highlight an item on each? It seems that when you select and item in one ListView the other is deselected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ListView` has a property [`HideSelection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.hideselection.aspx), which tells whether the selection remains highlighted when the control loses focus.

```
public bool HideSelection { get;  set; }
```

Set it to false either in the designer or through code:

```
listView1.HideSelection = false;
listView2.HideSelection = false;
```

Comment: It looks like I have the same situation (also two list views in one screen), however I can see both selections and did not use HideSelection... I cannot even find it in the properties of the list view.

Comment: @Michel: Are you using WinForms or WPF? You definitely have to set the `HideSelection` property to `false` in WinForms in order for the selected item to appear highlighted when the ListView control is not focused. The default value is `true`.

Comment: @Cody Gray Sorry I misread it, I use WPF instead of WinForms.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! Don't know how I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a freeware WinForms component [Better ListView Express](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview-express). It allows both **HideSelection** property and an extra **HideSelectionMode** property that allows [displaying items in *both* ListViews as selected regardless of the focus](http://www.componentowl.com/blog/2011/11/how-to-display-items-in-custom-states/).